# ¿Es estrictamente necesario una imagen Mysql en JHipster?

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, docker, jhipster

Tengo un proyecto creado con Jhipster y estoy por pasarlo a producción. El generador como tal crea un contenedor de la base de datos, en este caso Mysql. Al momento de generar la imagen con Docker y ejecutarla obviamente utiliza una imagen de la base de datos y crea un contenedor que realmente no estoy utilizando, pues, la conexión hacia la base de datos se encuentra en un servidor externo.

**La pregunta es si puedo evitar la utilización de una imagen de la base de datos y cómo puedo hacerlo en el proyecto JHipster?**

Mi duda es porque un proyecto Spring boot normal puedo correrlo sin utilizar una imagen de la base de datos, y quiero saber si para un projecto con Jhipster también sería posible eso ya que me ahorraría mucho espacio.

Disculpen si estoy confundido en algunos temas mencionados, no tengo dominio 100  % de los mismos y cualquier corrección o aclaración es bienvenida.

Muchas gracias.

Comment: Bienvenido a stackoverflow en español, puede que le interese leer esto 
[Recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour), puede tratar de mejorar 
su pregunta mirando este link [Como preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), 
es posible que su pregunta sea cerrada, ya que no cumple con los estándares del sitio, no se lo tome a mal. Saludos

Comment: A lo mejor estoy entendiendo mal, pero ¿Por qué un docker si puedes generar un `jar` con un servidor embebido de `tomcat` directamente desde spring boot? O un `war`. Según entiendo `docker` es para llevar todo tu ambiente incluida la BD y no tener que hacer más configuraciones que su implementación, pero si tu base es externa no le encuentro el motivo.

Comment: estar confundido con algo que tenga la palabra hipster en el nombre es normal, fijate si realmente necesitas jhipster o podes recrear el stack sin depender del producto

Answer (score 1):

Lo resolví de la siguiente forma:

En la ruta generada por Jhipster *{project}/src/main/docker* se encuentran los siguientes archivos:

- app.yml
- Dockerfile
- entrypoint.sh
- {database}.yml
- sonar.yml

Dentro del archivo *app.yml* es solo cuestión de comentar el servicio de la base de datos y comentar la linea de la configuración del `datasource` dentro del ambiente en el servicio de la aplicación. Para mi caso el archivo quedaría de la siguiente forma:

```
  version: '2'
  services:
      administrador-app:
          image: administradorapp
          environment:
              # - _JAVA_OPTIONS=-Xmx512m -Xms256m
              - SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=prod,swagger
              # - SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL=jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/reco?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8&useSSL=false
              - JHIPSTER_SLEEP=10 # gives time for the database to boot before the application
          ports:
              - 8080:8080
  #    administradorapp-mysql:
  #        extends:
  #            file: mysql.yml
  #            service: administradorapp-mysql
```